# How to find default account name in SQL Server Express property window?

Tags: sql-server

I have accidently cleared the account name text box in SQL Server Express property window in SQL Server Configuration Manager. Now I am unable to find how to get my current account name.

Please tell me how to find current account name... I have tried `[CurrentUserName]\SqlExpress` but failed.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: If you're using Windows Authentication method then you could try : `(local)` or `.` Or why not press the `Browse` button and see what Account Names are available, and then pick the right one? (if you said you forgot the name)

Comment: Still not working invalid password error because Account Name is incorrect

Comment: Did you try the `Browse` button and search for the account name?

Comment: Yes I have but no account name is working

Comment: How about `NT Service\SQLExpress`? Or how about using built-in account? Won't that be sufficient? (if you hopefully have mixed-login mode set up).

Comment: Your screenshot clearly shows that you are using the built-in `Local System` account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same issue with Me first clear password text boxes then paste this in AccountName Press ok.

NT Service\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS